# What is the status code that nginx deny all directive returns?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

For a configuration like this, what will be that HTTP status code for the denied requests? Will it be 403 or 404?

```
location / {
    allow MY_WHITE_LISTED_IP;
    deny  all;
}
```

I looked in the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#deny) but cannot find anything

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest to try it out?

Answer (score 1):

A denied request will have a [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) status.